# HTML Заголовки становятся ссылками

Tags: html, вёрстка

Почему-то HTML заголовки ссылаются на якорь cities. Вроде бы все парные закрыл.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Хьюстон</h1>
    <article><strong>Хьюстон</strong> (англ. Houston) — четвёртый по количеству жителей город в Соединённых Штатах Америки
    и крупнейший город в штате Техас с населением 2 319 603 человека на 2017 год. Хьюстон является
    административным центром округа Харрис, а также главным экономическим центром агломерации
    Большого Хьюстона с общим населением 6 772 470 человек на 2016 год. Город располагается в 50
    километрах от Мексиканского залива на прибрежной равнине.</article>
    <br>
    <article>Хьюстон был основан 30 августа 1836 года и включён в состав республики Техас 5 июня 1837 года,
    получив своё имя в честь Сэмюэла Хьюстона — главнокомандующего армией Техаса во время
    Техасской революции и президента Республики Техас. Быстрое развитие порта и железных дорог в
    XIX веке, а также начало добычи нефти и последовавшее развитие нефтяной промышленности в XX
    веке привели к быстрому росту населения. В 1960-е годы количество жителей превысило один
    миллион человек, а в 2000-е — два миллиона.</article>
    <br>
    <article>Город является ведущим мировым центром энергетической промышленности, а экономика города
    также представлена предприятиями в области аэронавтики, транспорта и здравоохранения.
    Важнейшими объектами для экономики и инфраструктуры города являются космический центр
    имени Линдона Джонсона, крупнейший американский по международным грузоперевозкам порт,
    хьюстонский судоходный канал, крупнейший в мире Техасский медицинский центр.</article>
    <h2>Содержание</h2>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#history">История</li>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#history_etim">Этимология, прозвища</li>
                <li><a href="#history_base">Основание</li>
                <li><a href="#history_cent">XX век</li>
            </ol>
        <li><a href="#phys_geo">Физико-географическая характеристика</li>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#phys_climate">Географическое положение и климат</li>
                <li><a href="#phys_relief">Рельеф, внутренние воды</li>
                <li><a href="#phys_flora">Флора и фауна</li>
            </ol>
        <li><a href="#economy">Экономика</li>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#eco_all">Общее состояние</li>
                <li><a href="#eco_energy">Энергетика и нефтехимия</li>
                <li><a href="#eco_space">Авиакосмическая промышленность</li>
            </ol>
        <li><a href="#population">Население</li>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#pop_dyn">Динамика и структура населения</li>
                <li><a href="#pop_etn">Этнический и конфессиональный состав, языки</li>
            </ol>
        <li><a href="#smi">Средства массовой информации</li>
        <li><a href="#cities">Города-побратимы</li>
    </ol>
    <h2 id="history">История</h2>
    <h3 id="history_etim">Этимология, прозвища</h3>
    <img src="C:\Users\ginib\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\HTML и CSS\photos huston\Sam_Houston_portrait.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У Вас ни один тег `a` не закрыт. Например `<li><a href="#history">История</li>`

Comment: Что значит "заголовки ссылаются на якорь"?